# AWK replace a string value in XML

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

In the File Test1.jmx I need to replace a string value to be false where the value = true or 0 or null. I need to do this for all occurrences of the string in the file.

```
before:
<boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">true</boolProp>
after:
<boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
```

Here's my erroneous code:

```
overrides_scheduler="BLAAA FOO MOO"
overRides=$(awk -v newValue="$overrides_scheduler" '$0 ~ /boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler"/ {a=$0; sub(/<boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">[a-zA-Z0-9]/,"<boolProp name=\"ThreadGroup.scheduler\">"newValue,a); print a; next;}{}1' "Test1.jmx");
echo  "$overRides" > "Test1.jmx"
```

Test1.jmx:

```
<boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">true</boolProp>
<longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1363247040000</longProp>
<longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1363247040000</longProp>
<boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">true</boolProp>
<longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1363247040000</longProp>
<boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">true</boolProp>
<boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler"></boolProp>
<longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1363247040000</longProp>
<boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">0</boolProp>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's|(<boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">)(true\|0\|null)(</boolProp>)|\1false\3|' Test1.jmx
```

Output:

```
<boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
<longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1363247040000</longProp>
<longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1363247040000</longProp>
<boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
<longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1363247040000</longProp>
<boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
<boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler"></boolProp>
<longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1363247040000</longProp>
<boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
```

Comment: thanks for this. It works really well. However, the null value was meant to represent no value at all rather than the word null. Would you know how I can adjust the statement so that false is replaces where there is no value?

Comment: @user1654528: Remove string `null` from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do the following:

```
echo '<boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">true</boolProp>' | awk -F'\">|</' '/ThreadedGroup.scheduler/ {sub(/true/,"false");print}'
```

Can also be used with `cat` or putting the filename at the end of the command.